# Nexmo: Forwarding 2 calls to the same LVN in nexmo

Tags: vonage

I had a scenario in which I need to forward call from two phone's using same Nexmo LVN. 
So its like this 
1. Phone_1 forwards call to Number_2 using LVN_1. 
2. Phone_2 will forward call to NUMBER_2 using same LVN_1.

Is this doable? If yes then how can we do it. I think call center does this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a single LVN. When you receive a call, you can use a [connect action](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/ncco-reference#connect) to dial out to another number. You'll need to change `from` to your LVN, and `number` to the phone number you want to forward on to in this example

`[
  {
    "action": "connect",
    "eventUrl": ["https://example.com/events"],
    "timeout": "45",
    "from": "447700900000",
    "endpoint": [
      {
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "447700900001"
      }
    ]
  }
]`

Comment: But for inbound call, do we get answer_url webhook?

Comment: For inbound call where can we give ncco object?

Comment: How do we figure out the original number that was called (which was forwarded to the LVN) ? The event\answer webhooks only receive - to (LVN) and from (Caller).

Comment: How are you forwarding to the LVN? `from` should be the original number that called the LVN

Comment: We enable call forwarding from PSTN to the Nexmo LVN by sending a message to the provider. Now all calls are forwarded to the LVN but without information about the number that was originally dialed.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with that the caller ID from your original provider isn't being preserved, and Nexmo is seeing the number from your other provider. Is that accurate?